# How to list users in a particular IRC group

Tags: chat, irc, channel

I am connecting to an IRC server ([Freenode IRC server](http://irc.freenode.org)) and am also entering into group *#ubuntu*.
Now I want list all the users in that group.

```
/list lists only the channels
```

Is there a command for listing users in that group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NAMES` protocol command lists the members of a channel.  This is often bound by clients to a `/names` command.

Comment: /names is showing all the nick names of all users in all the channels but I wanted to list only the users in particular channel eg. I want to list users in #neverwinterdp

Comment: @mehikmat: `/names #neverwinterdp`